# mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting (when same configs previously worked fine)

Tags: mount, nfs

Trying to remount a set of nfs folders onto a server that was restarted, am now getting "access denied by server" errors. On client server (clientserver.co.local) I ran:

```
[root@clientserver ~]# mount -t nfs -vvvv 172.18.4.97:/datalake/raw/org /datalake/org/raw/
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Dec 30 19:41:35 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=172.18.4.97,clientaddr=172.18.4.98'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.0,addr=172.18.4.97,clientaddr=172.18.4.98'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=172.18.4.97'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 172.18.4.97 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 172.18.4.97 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 20048
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 172.18.4.97:/datalake/raw/org
```

and got the error you see above. (Notice it tries all the different versions of nfs and still fails). Not sure which security flavor to use (I don't recall ever specifying this before and we use SSSD to link our Windows AD accounts to both client and nfs servers, so I assume it's the default), but in any case I've tried with both `-o sec=sys` and `-o sec=krb5` options and got the same results.

I ran `tcmpdump` to monitor the packet traffic during the mount command (based on the advice [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/mount-nfs-access-denied-by-server-while-mounting-how-to-resolve/)), but have no idea how to interpret the logs (could post something like last 10 lines if that would help).

Checking the mounts on the network from the hosting nfsserver.co.local server on the client, I saw:

```
[root@clientserver ~]# showmount -e
Export list for clientserver.co.local:
[root@clientserver ~]# showmount -e 172.18.4.97
Export list for 172.18.4.97:
/datalake/raw/org/HI_BRFSS               clientserver.co.local,otherclient.co.local
/datalake/raw/org                        clientserver.co.local,otherclient.co.local
/datalake/analytics/org                  clientserver.co.local,otherclient.co.local


[root@clientserver ~]# service nfs status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status nfs.service
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2020-12-30 18:32:09 HST; 11min ago
  Process: 93274 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 93271 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -au (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 93266 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd 0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 93307 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c if systemctl -q is-active gssproxy; then systemctl reload gssproxy ; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 93290 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 93288 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 93290 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-server.service

Dec 30 18:32:09 clientserver.co.local systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Dec 30 18:32:09 clientserver.co.local systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
```

So everything looks like how I would think it's supposed to (`showmount` does show the nfs folder I am trying to mount).

After running the `mount` command, the what I see in the `/var/log/messages` stream file is just a bunch of messages like

```
Jan  4 18:37:12 clientserver gssproxy: gssproxy[2557]: (OID: { 1 2 840 113554 1 2 2 }) Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, Client 'host/clientserver.co.local@ORG.LOCAL' not found in Kerberos database
```

Not sure what this means, but did check the gssproxy.conf file and it shows

```
[root@mclientserver ~]# cat /etc/gssproxy/gssproxy.conf 
[gssproxy]
```

Not sure what this means either, since I don't recall ever interacting with this in the past (when the nfs mount still worked).

We do use SSSD (did not set this up) to link our Windows AD accounts to the machine, but IDK if that would even be related here or if this is just something else. In any case, the sssd.conf is shown below

```
[root@clientserver ~]# cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf 

[sssd]
domains = co.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/co.local]
ad_domain = co.local
ad_server = adserver.CO.local
ad_backup_server = adserverbackup.CO.local
krb5_realm = CO.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba 
cache_credentials = False
enumerate = true
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = False
use_fully_qualified_names = False
override_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad
```

But other than that nothing in the logs seems to be more info than what I was already seeing from the command error...

```
[root@clientserver ~]# grep mount -rnw /var/log/messages* -e "nfs"
grep: mount: No such file or directory
/var/log/messages:2782:Jan  4 17:21:23 clientserver kernel: FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
/var/log/messages:2844:Jan  4 17:21:24 clientserver mount: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting nfsserver.co.local:/datalake/analytics/org
/var/log/messages:2845:Jan  4 17:21:24 clientserver mount: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting nfsserver.co.local:/datalake/raw/org
/var/log/messages-20201227:3590:Dec 23 17:46:04 clientserver kernel: FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[root@clientserver ~]# 
[root@clientserver ~]# 
[root@clientserver ~]# 
[root@clientserver ~]# grep mount -rnw /var/log/messages* -e "mount"
grep: mount: No such file or directory
/var/log/messages:2380:Jan  4 17:20:55 clientserver kernel: XFS (dm-3): Ending clean mount
/var/log/messages:2530:Jan  4 17:21:07 clientserver kernel: XFS (sda1): Ending clean mount
/var/log/messages:2537:Jan  4 17:21:07 clientserver kernel: XFS (dm-5): Ending clean mount
/var/log/messages:2844:Jan  4 17:21:24 clientserver mount: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting nfsserver.co.local:/datalake/analytics/org
/var/log/messages:2845:Jan  4 17:21:24 clientserver mount: mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting nfsserver.co.local:/datalake/raw/org
/var/log/messages:2846:Jan  4 17:21:24 clientserver systemd: datalake-org-analytics.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32
/var/log/messages:2847:Jan  4 17:21:24 clientserver systemd: Failed to mount /datalake/org/analytics.
/var/log/messages:2850:Jan  4 17:21:24 clientserver systemd: Unit datalake-org-analytics.mount entered failed state.
/var/log/messages:2851:Jan  4 17:21:24 clientserver systemd: datalake-org-raw.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32
/var/log/messages:2852:Jan  4 17:21:24 clientserver systemd: Failed to mount /datalake/org/raw.
/var/log/messages:2853:Jan  4 17:21:24 clientserver systemd: Unit datalake-org-raw.mount entered failed state.
/var/log/messages:3014:Jan  4 17:21:27 clientserver dracut: Executing: /usr/sbin/dracut --hostonly --hostonly-cmdline --hostonly-i18n -o "plymouth dash resume ifcfg" --mount "/dev/mapper/centos_mapr001-root /sysroot xfs defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=0" --no-hostonly-default-device -f /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-862.6.3.el7.x86_64kdump.img 3.10.0-862.6.3.el7.x86_64
/var/log/messages-20201227:3669:Dec 23 17:47:35 clientserver systemd: mapr.mount mounting timed out. Stopping.
/var/log/messages-20201227:3823:Dec 23 17:47:37 clientserver systemd: Unit mapr.mount entered failed state.
[root@clientserver ~]#
[root@clientserver ~]#
[root@clientserver ~]#
[root@clientserver ~]# tail -n 15 /var/log/dmesg
[  148.561016] piix4_smbus 0000:00:01.3: SMBus Host Controller at 0x700, revision 0
[  148.643519] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  148.643580] sd 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  148.643639] sd 0:0:2:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  148.643846] sd 0:0:3:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  148.643907] sd 0:0:4:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[  148.643962] sd 0:0:5:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[  148.644030] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 5
[  148.718917] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[  148.723858] Adding 8900604k swap on /dev/mapper/centos_mapr001-swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8900604k FS
[  148.865301] XFS (sda1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[  149.497874] XFS (sda1): Ending clean mount
[  150.110208] XFS (dm-5): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[  150.190558] XFS (dm-5): Ending clean mount
[  150.966314] type=1305 audit(1609816868.676:4): audit_pid=2500 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=1
```

I can `ping` the nfsserver machine by both name and IP address from the client (and vice versa from the nfsserver machine).

Checking the SE Linux settings, I see...

```
[root@clientserver /]$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

I did not set these (or really have much experience with SE Linux), but the "permissive" makes me think that it should not be a firewall problem.

I've heard that there could port issues that can cause this kind of thing. When I use `rpcinfo` I see

```
[root@clientserver ~]# rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  34584  status
    100024    1   tcp  53605  status
    100005    1   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
    100005    2   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd
    100005    3   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100021    1   udp  36667  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  36667  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  36667  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  39608  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  39608  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  39608  nlockmgr
```

but I really don't know much about networking stuff to say if this is normal of not.

Looking on the nfsserver server, I see:

```
[root@nfsserver ~]# cat /etc/exports
/datalake/analytics/org         otherclient(rw,no_root_squash,sync) clientserver(rw,root_squash,sync)
/datalake/raw/org               otherclient(rw,no_root_squash,sync) clientserver(ro,root_squash,sync)
/datalake/raw/org/HI_BRFSS      otherclient(ro,no_root_squash,sync) clientserver(ro,root_squash,sync)
[root@nfsserver ~]# exportfs -rav
exporting otherclient.co.local:/datalake/raw/org/HI_BRFSS
exporting clientserver.co.local:/datalake/raw/org/HI_BRFSS
exporting otherclient.co.local:/datalake/raw/org
exporting clientserver.co.local:/datalake/raw/org
exporting otherclient.co.local:/datalake/analytics/org
exporting clientserver.co.local:/datalake/analytics/org


[root@nfsserver ~]# systemctl status nfs
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2020-12-30 18:38:00 HST; 22min ago
  Process: 135417 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 135414 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -au (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 135412 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd 0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 135447 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c if systemctl -q is-active gssproxy; then systemctl reload gssproxy ; fi (code=exited, status=
0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 135430 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 135428 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 135430 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-server.service

Dec 30 18:38:00 nfsserver.co.local systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Dec 30 18:38:00 nfsserver.co.local systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
```

So again, everything seems to be configured as needed. (I have seen some answers that recommend a specific configuration for `/etc/exports` but I'd prefer to keep as is and this configuration was working up until now). And changing the DNS name to the IP in the nfsserver's `/etc/exports` file and running `exportfs -rav` did not change the situation.

Anyone with more experience know what could be going wrong here? Any further debugging advice / info to add that would make this question better (eg. anyone see anything in this post where further investigation into a certain possibility should be done)?

Comment: Did anything on the client change after it was restarted? Do the logs say anything? Can `nfsserver` resolve `clientserver`? Have you tried to add `/datalake/raw/org <ip_address>(ro,root_squash,sync)` to `/etc/fstab` just to rule it out?

Comment: @NasirRiley Yeah, tried that. Added a line like `nfsserver.org.local:/datalake/raw/org /datalake/org/raw/  nfs ro 0 0` to the clientserver's `/etc/fstab` and restarting, but not mounted and seeing same problem. What did you mean by "do the logs say anything"? What location could I check for any relevant logs here?

Comment: My mistake. That line should be added to `/etc/exports` and after, restart the `nfs` service. The line that you added to `/etc/fstab` is the name, not the IP address. Can you ping `nfsserver` from `clientserver`? The log that you can look at is `/var/log/messages` on the client and on the server. If you're going to use Linux, it's important to know to examine logs.

Comment: After running the `mount` command, I do see messages of the form "Jan  4 18:37:12 clientserver gssproxy: gssproxy[2557]: (OID: { 1 2 840 113554 1 2 2 }) Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, Client 'host/clientserver.co.local@ORG.LOCAL' not found in Kerberos database", but not totally sure what this means (updated post with more info in any case)

Comment: Which security flavour is the mount supposed to use? Plain old `sec=sys` (1:1 mapping of users/groups, no user authentication), or Kerberos (`sec=krb5/krb5i/krb5p`)? The GSS error means that Kerberos is likely not configured properly. By the way, look into the kernel log `dmesg` to see any errors related to the mount. The `mount` utility itself will never give you a lot of details about what went wrong, because all it gets from the kernel is a single error code.

Comment: By the way, if this is supposed to run over NFSv4, you can ignore `rpcinfo`/portmapper concerns. Those are all only for NFS <= 3.

Comment: @TooTea Not sure which security flavor it wants (I don't recall ever specifying this before, so I assume it's the default), but in any case I've tried with both `-o sec=sys` and `-o sec=krb5` options and got the same results. Added the last few lines of `/var/log/dmesg` after running the `mount` command again to the post, but they don't look like there is much there.

Comment: @It doesn't "want" any particular security flavour, it's about what you want to use (how is your setup supposed to work). `sys` implies trust between the client and server, there's no user authentication, user `foo` on the client gets full access to files of user `foo` on the server. With Kerberos, there's no such trust or direct mapping needed, whoever has the appropriate Kerberos tickets gets access to the corresponding data. These are two completely different modes of operation.

Comment: @TooTea I see. Then I assume it's the default then since we use SSSD to link our Windows AD accounts to both the client and nfs server (and I've never had to specify it when mounting in the past)

Answer (score 0):

If your system drive is out of space on your NFS server:

1. you will get `mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting` messages on clients
2. the nfs service will look fine via `systemctl status nfs-kernel-server`
3. logs will likely show nothing amiss (though there may be something obviously amiss with your logs, since you're out of space)

Posting this answer as the symptoms are quite similar (sudden unexplained 'access denied' errors when trying to mount NFS server resources that have been fine, on a server that responds to pings and looks okay)

Remedy is all the usual stuff when you run out of space - logs, Docker containers, etc.